# Tell XMLReader to ignore provided namespace info

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I'm using an instance of PHPs built-in `XMLReader` to read some kind of user-generated XML file. Usually this XML files content starts like the following sample snippet, where everything works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openimmo>
  <uebertragung art="OFFLINE" umfang="VOLL" version="1.2.7" (...)
```

However, another user uses a different software to send and generate the XML file. The XML generated by this software starts like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openimmo xmlns="http://www.openimmo.de" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openimmo.de openimmo.xsd">
  <uebertragung art="OFFLINE" umfang="VOLL" version="1.2.7" (...)
```

Which causes my importer to fail with the following error:

```
XMLReader::read(): Element '{http://www.openimmo.de}openimmo': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
```

I'm already doing validation by manually applying some XSD schema. The passed file follows the same schema, just explicitly specifies the `xmlns` attributes. How can I work around this issue? How can I tell `XMLReader` to just ignore that `xmlns` statement?

My code (simplified to the relevant sections) looks like the following snippet:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$success = @$reader->open($path);
if (!$success) { /* error handling */ }
$reader->setSchema($localOpenImmoXsdPath);
/* then starts reading and throws the above exception */
```

Comment: Some more note: Not enforcing the schema with `setSchema` does not lead to error. (Actually the whole import does work then, but that seems risky.)

Comment: (Only hypothesising)Is there some change in your schema that can make the other schema valid, or perhaps having to create a new schema which validates according to the new file may be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace information is fundamental and there's no way an XML parser is going to ignore it.

Your options are either (a) send the file back to sender, saying it doesn't conform to the agreed schema, or (b) transform the file sent to you so that it does conform, by changing the namespace. That's a fairly simple XSLT transformation.

My immediate instinct was to look at the OpenImmo specs to see what they say about namespaces and schema conformance, but unfortunately access to the specs requires registration and licensing. Basically, either the specs allow both these formats, which would be a pretty shoddy spec, or they only allow one of them, in which case you shouldn't be accepting both.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable help. Sending back the file is not a solution. The customer which operates the sending software did not implement it (it is actually a standard software, sold a few hundred times). Sadly, the license terms of the OpenImmo standard do not allow me to publish the specs. However, googling "openimmo_127.xsd" shows that at least the XSD file has been leaked on some Github repos.

Comment: It looks like this is a long-standing problem: see https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200906/msg00144.html The schema says the elements are in no-namespace, but there seems to be an established practice of using the namespace `http://www.openimmo.de`; if that's the case, then as a consumer of the documents, you probably need to accept both. The best way of handling two variants of a document format that differ only (or mainly) in namespace is to start by transforming to a single common format.